# Make JSON data from App.vue accessible in all views

Tags: json, api, vue.js

My Vue3 SSA so far consists of the following files:
App.vue
views/Home
views/Page_A
views/Page_B

In App.vue a JSON file is loaded via an API. The data is needed on the home page and on pages A and B.
With the following code, I load the data from the API and if it is done in each view file separately, I can use it in the corresponding template.

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
    name: "RenderList",
    props: {
        msg: String,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            listDataString: String,
            listData: [], // placeholder
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        axios
            .get('https://www.dev.domain.de/wp/wp7/all_json/?maxCounts=20&order=DESC')
            .then((response) => {
                this.listDataString = JSON.stringify(response.data, null, "\t");
                this.listData = response.data;
                console.log(this.listData);
                return response; // multiline arrow function must return
            });
    },
};
</script>
```

But since the API data does not change, it would be enough to load it once in the App.vue and then make it available to the view files.

What is the correct procedure to distribute the data?
I just found a way to store in localStorage, but this way could be disabled by the user.
Maybe i just need a hint and no code, so i can find out myself.

Comment: If this is a small project, components implemented under the `root` Vue instance can have  their properties accessed through `this.$root`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your comment @Ohgodwhy

So my solution is much easier than i thought.
This is usable in every view.vue:

```
<table id="items">
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in this.$root.listData" :key="index">
        <td class="p-1">{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td class="p-1">{{ item.city }}</td>
        <td class="p-1">{{ item.country }}</td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```