# Using a dynamic URl to select a '$root' object entry in Vue3

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

In my Vue3 app the `$root` object has the `listData` entry.
[Make JSON data from App.vue accessible in all views](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69533049/8110291)
This entry contains many (> 1.000) objects (e.g. cars) with always the same properties (ID, name, etc.).

I want to create a page that shows the properties of a single object. (Car.name, Car.motor, Car.image, etc).
Using a wildcard in the route I forward the requests to the `details.vue`:

```js
{ path: '/:path(.*)', component: details, props:true, },
```

And one hardcoded link:

```js
<router-link to="/Car_1">Car_1</router-link>
```

This works.

Then I want to find the corresponding entry from the `$root.listData` object and output it:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      dataSS: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    let name = this.$route.params.path;
    let data = this.$root.listData;
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      const el = data[i];
      // console.log(el.ID)
      if (el.name === name) {
        this.dataSS = data[i]
      }
    }
  },
}
```

This also works, if the page is linked to via the
`<router-link>`, but not if the page is called directly from the browser.
Then the for loop works but the array `dataSS[]` remains empty.

First, is this the 'right' way to achieve my goal, or is there a better one?
Secondly, how can it be achieved that they are also displayed in a direct call?

#### edit, after the first comment from StevenSiebert @19:11

The assumption is correct that `this.$root.listData` is still empty when the for loop starts. So `dataSS` can have no content at all.

By chance I became aware of the `.filter()` function:

```js
computed: {
    dataSS: function () {
        this.dataSS = this.$root.listData.filter(SS => SS.name == this.$route.params.path)[0];
        return this.dataSS
    },
},
```

With this, displaying the content via the `<router-link>` and after the browser refresh works.

However, I get the following error message in the console after the browser refresh:

```js
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $options.dataSS is undefined
```

But this only if I access a property of the object `{{ dataSS.name }}` and not if the object is displayed as a whole `{{ dataSS }}`.
Even predefining dataSS makes no difference.

```js
data() {
    return {
        dataSS: { 'country': '', 'city': '', 'foundingyear': '', 'name': '' }
    };
},
```

Why does the error message only appear when I access the properties, but not the whole object?
Why does predefining not prevent the error?

Answer (score 1):

I assume `this.$root.listData` isn´t loaded when you call the url in the browser, as your app "restarts" when you call it manually, it is like a browser refresh. I recommend to use `vuex` with `vuex-persistedstate` to have your data available even after reloading.

When you do this, you can use your function as `async` and `await` to ensure you don´t run it without data.

Comment: You´r  right, `this.$root` isn´t loaded at this time. I tried a different way, see my edit. If that is not a solution, i will have a look at `vuex`.

Comment: @kolja If this is you actual code, there will be a conflict between the data property `dataSS` and computed property `dataSS`. Using something like `webpack` this should throw an error like `error Duplicated key 'dataSS'  vue/no-dupe-keys`.